# How do I make stun/turn safe?

Tags: security, webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I need to make a video chat. In order to make it work I need a stun/turn server. The problem is that I have no idea how to make secure authorization in them. I use coturn, but even if I connect a database, it would be very painful to add users to the system, manage passwords. If I could use coturn along with passport.js inside node.js to allow only users who are logged in, but I can't even imagine how that would be possible.

Anyway, how does this work in services like zoom? This security hole in the form of an accessible stun/turn server is keeping me busy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generally accepted solution for this is time-limited credentials as described in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-uberti-behave-turn-rest-00 combined with monitoring of your turn servers to assert that the users  the credentials were given to are not abusing them (for some definition of that)

Comment: Sounds good. Do you know how to implement it with coturn? I'm having a hard time figuring it out. Maybe there's an example where this has already been implemented? I don't care about the language of implementation, because it will be using API.

Comment: I seem to have it figured out, but an example would be nice to see, too. Thank you!